# Charging supercapacitors with Buck converter. Do I need to cut power once charge is reached?

Tags: power-supply, charger, buck, charging, supercapacitor

I am trying to build a supercapacitor charger, and as I don't particularly have a good handle on the risks of such a thing, I'm hopping on here to give some information.

I am using a buck converter connected to a 12v power supply to feed my 2 2.7v supercaps (in series, 5.4 is what I want to cap the charge at)

I have the pot on the buck converter set at 5.4v.

What's the risk in actually not having a cutoff? It's not like caps on a computer motherboard have a cutoff, right? They're constantly receiving a charge.

Once the cap is charged, the amp draw should be close to nothing, right?

If I felt compelled to cut off power at 5.4 volts, what would be an easy way to do so?

Comment: What exactly are you building this for? The more specific you can be about your end goal, the more useful an answer we can give.

Comment: The end result is nothing more than a simple "battery bank" with a very high discharge rate. I haven't quite decided what to do with it yet because I haven't figured out how to charge it safely. I suppose more or less it's going to be my introduction into building more powerful banks with supercaps. Starting with the caps and how to charge them was the first step in my mind.

Comment: this may be simple.....have a small ADC and measure voltage and cut off the Buck once cap fully charged......

Comment: Is there anything off the shelf I can buy and look at, so I can either build one or use it for this purpose?

Comment: Dead cheap solution: A timer hooked up to your power source.

Comment: Dead cheap perhaps, but what if the caps are discharged to 75%, and then recharged, or the cycle status is unknown, say at 70%, but I assume it's at 0%? Of course I can just sit there with a multimeter until charge is reached, but I am looking for a solution where I don't have to do that.

Comment: Supercaps **MUST NOT** be charged to above their rate voltage. Some (few) versions also have a lower voltage limit that you must not discharge below. Damage to the capacitor is likely to occur if either limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Charging capacitors isn't very complicated. The capacitors will charge up to, and hold at, the voltage of your source. Really no need to turn off the source once the capacitors are fully charged. Once the capacitors match the voltage of the source, no more current will flow and the system will be stable*.

If you do desire to have some kind of cutoff, there is any number of ways to do it. A simple mechanical switch is probably the best option. That way the capacitors are physically isolated from the power source. The switch could be something you manipulate with your finger or on a relay that can be electronically switched based on logic.

Here's a few pointers that come to mind:

1. I wouldn't recommend charging 2.7V capacitors up to 2.7V. Like any other system, if you operate it at its rated maximum capacity, it may shorten its lifespan. Plus, if the voltage source fluctuates a little high for some reason, it could cause the caps to explode in spectacular fashion. Give yourself a little margin to play it safe.
2. A large bank of uncharged capacitors will look like a dead short to ground the instant you attach them to the charger. Unless you're working with heavy equipment, the buck converter you're using probably won't like the initial current surge. A simple resistor between the voltage source and the capacitor bank will limit the current, but still allow the capacitors to get fully charged. It will just take a little longer. Just chose the maximum current you want and apply Ohm's Law to calculate the resistor. Don't forget to account for power dissipation!
3. I hopefully don't need to mention that large capacitor banks can become very dangerous when handled. Lots of stored energy and very low ESR is a recipe for an exciting day if you're not careful.

*In reality there will be a small amount of leakage current, so the system will never truly reach zero current.

Comment: Awesome answer. This is along the lines of what I thought. I will charge to 5.2 volts instead. Do you think a 2.5 ohm resistor will be enough to maintain a 1.5-2 amp charge rate and prevent damage to the converter? The buck converter I am using has a rated output amperage of 5.

Comment: 2.5 Ohm with a 5.2V source will give you a max current surge of 2A, so yeah, that looks good. Do the power dissipation calculation (I^2*R) and make sure you digest that number. Granted, the inital power surge will be short and the current will rapidly fall off. But still a good idea to make sure the resistor can handle the heat.

Comment: I plan on sinking it with all these alumina heatsinks I came across a while back. Hopefully it's all enough. Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 3):

With supercaps in series (just like normal capacitors), one will charge to a higher voltage than the other statistically because their capacitances are unlikely to be exactly equal. I'd probably consider charging them all in parallel then have a circuit that wired them in series.

Consider that one capacitor is 1.1 farads whilst the other is 0.9 farads. If you apply 5.2 volts across the series pair, the 0.9 farad capacitor will charge up to 2.86 volts whilst the 1.1 farad device will charge to only 2.34 volts.

So you either build a circuit that charges in parallel or you reduce your 5.2 volts down to maybe 4.8 volts to accommodate tolerance differences in values between supercaps.

Comment: I certainly don't want overcharging. I will consider this in my design.

Answer (score 1):

A simple voltage regulator with a fold-back current limiting fits the bill for charging a supercapacitor very well. The voltage for the regulator should be set for the maximum voltage you want to charge the capacitor which should be a little lower than the rating for the capacitor. The maximum current needs to be reasonable for your power source and low enough to not over-heat the capacitor. You can use the capacitor's maximum ripple current - 20% as a good maximum current value. Smaller supercapacitors may not specify a maximum ripple current but you can typically charge them at a rate of 1 ampere being very conservative. Larger capacitors can handle 3-4 amperes.

The charging rate will determine how much time it takes to charge the capacitor. So if you need it charged quickly you will need a high charge rate. If you don't care about how fast it is you can charge it at a lower rate which will extend the life of the entire system. Unlike a battery capacitors charge in a linear curve which gives you the ability to use a simple trick to start charging at a higher rate and end up charging slower as the voltage rises. Simply insert a small value resistor somewhere in the rate of 2 - 10 ohms in series with the charging circuit. This is low enough to allow a high charge rate when the capacitor is discharged, but will slow down the rate as the voltage in the capacitor rises. This allows you to start fast but keep the temperature of the capacitor down over time.

Capacitors can keep charged continuously without adversely affecting the life. What kills capacitors is heat and capacitors leakage current internally. The leakage is typically only a few milli-amperes so the heat is easily dissipated. However if other components in the system are generating heat and that heat transfers to the capacitor then it will affect the lifetime on the capacitor. For this reason I would suggest using a switch regulator to charge to capacitor unless you choose a low current charge rate ( < 300 ma).

As I mentioned above your voltage regulator should have folder-back current limiting which means that it will still try to supply power to the load even when the maximum current level is reached. The voltage will drop but the regulator will supply power to its maximum current limit. Some regulators shut down entirely when overloaded and thus does not supply power to the load at all. Typically they turn back on after some period of time but will just trip again. Many times the limiting is just a result of the regulator doing its best until is gets too hot and then shutting itself down.

Most switch regulator work great for this purpose when they use cycle to cycle current limiting. What this means is they turn on and start supplying power to the load and if the current limit is reached before the voltage level is reached it turns off earlier. The means that the capacitor will see an average voltage of just enough to charge the capacitor at the desired maximum rate. This also means that the power supply is not heating up more than normal even though the capacitor is overloading the power supply.

Never apply a higher voltage to the capacitor than it is rated for. Not all parts of the capacitor will have identical characteristics like leakage, series resistance, and dielectric constant. The means that while to capacitor is not fully charged some portion of the capacitor may be at the maximum voltage while other parts are not. If the charging voltage is higher than the rated voltage then the parts that are fully charged will see the full voltage because they are not dropping some of the voltage through the internal resistance. This can cause a voltage breakdown that damages the capacitor.

When stacking supercapacitors you have to balance them because breakdown voltage are so low that they don't allow for much tolerance. At low charging currents a simple zener diode can be used. At higher charge currents using a zener and a transistor as a shunt-regulator will do the job. Another consideration is when the capacitor is be used to supply power the voltage will drop in a linear fashion so if you are trying to get 5V or 3.3V from the capacitor the run-time will be limited is less half of the energy in the capacitor because the voltage will drop too low. Using a Boost or a buck-boost switching regulator to supply power to the load from the capacitor will allow you to draw power from the capacitor to the minimum voltage that the boost regulator can manage. This can easily extend the run time by double.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a 5V schottky diode (and possibly a voltage divider if you want to charge above 5v) that opens a relay or similar, thus physically opening the circuit once the 5v is reached

you would also want to balance the voltages across the two caps, outside of measuring them to have very similar capacities, you could use another voltage divider that allows a small current to pass such that each capacitor gets an equal voltage across it, and then use the relay from the previous part to disconnect this voltage divider once the capacitors are charged.